# Why is the google chromecast extension not injecting API on a whitelisted domain

Tags: google-chrome, google-cast, chromecast

I got a couple of domains whitelisted. Let's say they are a.mydomain.com and b.mydomain.com

I went to developer options in the chromecast extension and whitelisted mydomain.com and added data-cast-api-enabled=”true” to the html tag

At this point, I was expecting the extension to inject api_script.js (like the one that I am seeing on youtube and netflix)

What am I missing here?

Comment: In the extension, did you whitelist mydomain.com or *.mydomain.com? If the former, then the whitelisting may not extend to a.mydomain.com and b.mydomain.com ... try whitelisting the wildcard (or the subdomains directly) in the extension. (Also, make sure you aren't appending any protocol to the domain name when whitelisting).

Answer (score 1):

There are two whitelisting procedures listed in the developer documentation.

The first is [device whitelisting](https://developers.google.com/cast/whitelisting) (under "Whitelisting your receiver device"). During this process you provide 1 or 2 target URLs to the Google Cast team, and they generate an application ID for you. Then when launching a session with the Cast API from a device (Android, iOS, or Chrome browser with extension installed) you provide the string `"<applicationId>_<urlNumber>"` and the receiver you select will then open the receiver page located at the URL associated with that string.

The second whitelisting (under "Whitelisting Chrome apps" at the link above) is specific to developing a sender app with the Chrome extension, and is configured within the browser. The Chrome extension will only inject the Cast API into specific sender pages currently, but allows developers to whitelist the domain their sender pages are on.

> 1. Be sure you are running Chrome version 28 or later.
>
>    - If you haven't restarted Chrome in a while you may be running an older version; restarting will update Chrome automatically.
> 2. In the Chrome address field, enter chrome://extensions, and check the Developer mode checkbox to enable developer mode.
> 3. Install the Chrome extension for Google Cast.
> 4. On the Cast extension icon in the browser's upper right corner (next to the address field), right-click and select Options.
>
>    - The Google Cast extension options page opens in a new tab.
> 5. On the blue Cast icon, in the page's upper left corner, click four (4) times.
>
>    - The Developer Settings appear.
> 6. In the Cast SDK additional domains field, enter your application's domain, for example, "www.mydomain.com" and click Add.
> 7. Code your application's HTML tag as follows:
>
>    ```
>    <html data-cast-api-enabled=”true”>
>    ```
> 8. Reload the application's page.

Answer (score 0):

I observed that the issue was a Javascript error on that page which prevented the injection of cast api by the extension. (Was missing jquery)

I have able to get the injected JS on all other pages